# How could I accomplish this in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a feeling the following might be an atrocity, and maybe that's why it doesn't work.
So here I am, asking for your help. :-)

Also please help me edit this question. I do not know what would be an appropiate title for it or a better way to formulate it. (Like you have probably guessed by now, English is not my native language).

Consider a class like:

```
public class Order
{
  public int FareCode;
  public int Quantity;
}
```

Then a Linq query like:

```
var orders = new []{ new Order {...}, ...};
var fareCodes = orders.Select(o => o.FareCode).ToArray();
using(var dc = new datacontext())
{
  var query = dc.Fares
              .Where(f => fareCodes.Contains(f.FareCode))
              .Select(f => new {
                Fare = f,
                Quantity = orders.Single(o => o.FareCode == f.FareCode).Quantity //<-- This is not right!
              })
}
```

So `Quantity = Orders.Single(o => o.FareCode == f.FareCode).Quantity` ins't right. So what would be another option to accomplish this?

UPDATE: The reason it does not work is because the runtime throws this exception: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator

Comment: What are you trying to get as the end result?

Comment: Why "this is not right" ? Does it raise an exception ?

Comment: Are you trying to update Quantity property values from a data source?

Comment: I'm trying to get the Fare Entities with the corresponding quantity.

Comment: I'm trying to build an Service Order with the especified Fares (Tarifas in Spanish)

Comment: It does not work because of an exception: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator

Comment: @Unlimited071 - check my updated answer - try ToList() before using Select()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your last comment, try this solution:

```
var query = Fares
        .Where(f => fareCodes.Contains(f.FareCode)).ToList()
        .Select(f => new
                         {
                             Fare = f,
                             Quantity = Orders.Single(o => o.FareCode == f.FareCode).Quantity
                         });
```

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like for each `Order`, you want to change the `FareCode` into the associated `Fare`,  and sum the quantities of each `Fare` without hitting your datacontext for every single `Order`.

I would use GroupBy/ToDictionary combo on the `Orders` list, and `ToDictionary()` on the `Fares` list:

```
// generates a dictionary of fare codes and total quantity of orders per fare code
var fareQuantities = Orders.GroupBy(o => o.FareCode).ToDictionary(og => og.Key, og => og.Sum(o => o.Quantity));

using(var dc = new datacontext())
{
    var query = dc.Fares
        .Where(f => fareQuantities.Keys.Contains(f.FareCode))
        .ToDictionary(f => f, f => fareQuantities[f.FareCode]);
    // query is now a dictionary of fares and the total quantities of each fare ordered
}
```

Hope that helps.